# Close jQuery popup (external page) window

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, modalpopups

Setup:

Popup Page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>popup page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="txtArea">Comments:</label>
        <textarea id="txtArea" type="text" rows="5" cols="25">
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />&nbsp;
            <input type="button" value="cancel" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Main Page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>popup page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="lnkPopup">Post Comment</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem:

I want to open the popup page on clicking of link in main page. This is easily achievable with so many awsome jQuery plugins, but tht problem is that I want to close the popup when user clicks `submit` or `cancel` button. How can I achieve this? I have seen exemples where another block from same page is shown and we have `IDs` of elements in it but not the external page.

Comment: This is highly dependent on the dialog plugin your are using. Most of them have a `close` method you can trigger

Comment: @JohnP but how can I trigger from external popup page? that is really the issue. I am open with `plugin` suggestions.

Comment: well, if it's an actual popup you can use `window.opener`. That will give you access to the parent

Comment: @JohnP if it is an actual pop up then there is no problem. It is to be modal popup.

Comment: It's the same principle. Simply create a reference to the object you used to create the modal and access it through `window.opener` How you close it would depend on what script you use, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already using jQuery you could open your popup as a *modal window*.

One good plugin for this scenario is [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/home)

From within the modal window you can easily close the window pressing the submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#yourform").submit(function() {
       parent.$.fancybox.close();
     });});
</script>
```